# ASPxDropDownEdit - empty when Edit button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have a funny situation in my Project.
 In my page i have a Formview which is bound to an Entity by the Name Project.Basicaly a project could be depend on other projects which could be more than one(So i need Combobox with MultiSelection which im making it up -using 10.1.5 so i cant use Aspxlookup) .
 Formview is Readonly by default at the Page Load.I have an Entity which is ProjectDependency which records Project dependencies.
 when the page is loading perfectly filling up the Combox and shows the Selected projects.Now i need to click on Edit button which changes the Mode to Formview Edit.After clicking on Edit button when i open Combox is just blank???? If i click Edit button once more then it filling it up with selected Items.

I attached a test project.I also attached the screenshots.
 Thx for ur help in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny Mistake, The Combobox in FormView in ReadOnlyMode and EditMode had the Same ID ,
LOL
Copy paste issue hahahhahaah